# Slim PHP in sub directory not working

Tags: php, http, class, rest, slim

I have the slim (http://www.slimframework.com/) directory unpacked in 
http://example.com/api/

and I have the index.php file looking as such:

```
<?php

    require 'Slim/Slim.php';

    Slim::init();

    Slim::get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {

        echo "Hello $name";

    });

    Slim::run();

?>
```

but when I try to access the GET method, The browser returns something like:

> Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error.

And I have no idea why it's not working.

Help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to clarify, I do have PHP 5.3, but I also tried in the 5.2 way, and it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution to this problem was HTTP version number within Slim's package.

I changed this line

```
        header('HTTP/1.1 ' . self::getMessageForCode($this->status()));
```

to

```
        header('HTTP/1.0 ' . self::getMessageForCode($this->status()));
```

and all was well.

Cheers, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify the .htaccess file accordingly and make sure it's in the right spot?  Also, try adding this line to it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: I've found that most of the issues I had with Slim were due to my .htaccess file being wrong.

Comment: thanks, I forgot about this question. It turns out the problem was due to http version.